# What is "The R Interpreter" setting in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: r, intellij-idea

My OS is Windows 7. I have installed "IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5", and "R x64 3.1.2".

I'm going to do some R language coding in IntelliJ IDEA. So I installed the plugin "IntelliJ plugin for the R language". Then I'm blocked by its setting, at File->Settings->Other Settings->The R Interpreter.

I have no idea of what is "R Interpreter". Which file is it?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [IntelliJ plugin for the R language](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8257?pr=).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry I'm a so newbie of IntelliJ IDEA. 
And I got the answer. The R Interpreter means the x64/R.exe file in my R installation folder. 
But still don't know how to set the "Sources" in that same page.

Answer (score 4):

Goto Preferences->Languages->R
or File->Settings->Languages->R Language

Then browse the location where you have installed R and after going to that location goto "bin" folder and then choose R.exe file.
Now after browsing "........./R/R-<*version*>/bin/R.exe" by following the above instructions click on <kbd>Apply</kbd> and then <kbd>Ok</kbd>.
That's it. You are done then.
Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First, go to `File -> Settings -> Languages -> R Language,` click the `...` and go to (if you picked the default R installation options) `C:/Program Files/R/[R version]/bin/` and double-click `R.exe.`